# nonstandard topology?

Tags: general-topology, nonstandard-models

It is possible to have nonstandard models of PA where the natural numbers are different.

The definition of a topology requires a notion of finiteness.

> What happens if we use a nonstandard model of arithmetic to say what finiteness means in the definition of topology?

Comment: That's a very nice question! Kudos!

Comment: Also, non-standard analysis while related to non-standard models of $\sf PA$, is not really involved in this question. Perhaps one of the set theoretical tags would fit, but I wasn't sure. (The title could probably use a little improvement too.)

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that we needn't use arithmetic to define finiteness at all. For example, a set $S$ of sets is finite (in the sense we're used to) if and only if each non-empty subset of the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of $S$ has a minimal element with respect to inclusion ($\subseteq$). A general set $X$ (not necessarily a set of sets) is finite if and only if every injection $X\to X$ is a surjection. Alternately, $X$ is finite if and only if every inductive family of subsets of $X$ contains $X$. An inductive family of subsets of $X$ is a set $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of $X$, such that $\emptyset\in \mathcal{A}$, and such that for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$ and all $x\in X$ we have $A\cup\{x\}\in\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Every collection of disjoint sets contains a minimal element with respect to $\subseteq$, finite or not.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Oh, dear! Thank you for catching that! Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

The definitions of topology require some notion of set theory. Therefore we need to work in a theory which is stronger than that of $\sf PA$.

Mostly we work in $\sf ZFC$, or some variation of it. The important part is that these theories prove the consistency of $\sf PA_2$, that is the second-order theory of $\sf PA$, which is categorical. So internally to a universe of $\sf ZFC$ there is no such thing as a non-standard integer.

Of course, there are many different ways of defining finiteness (especially in $\sf ZFC$), which do not make any appeal to the integers themselves. But the point is that topology is working within the universe of a theory that proves that all the integers are standard (again, internally, it might be the case that the model itself does have non-standard integers, but it cannot know about it from an internal point of view).

Comment: These fine points about internal/external issues can be confusing, I'll be happy to refine my answer if you have particular points that you want me to add.